# How to access attributes returned as a Mono object separately using Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive

I developed a REST service with the help of reactive programming in Spring Boot.I was able to retrieve the data as a mono object.But I need to capture only the necessary attribute from that Mono object returned

```
public Mono<Boolean> getUserAddress(User userRequest) {
    Mono<User> user =  userRepository.findByUsername(userRequest.getUsername());

   return user.filter(usr -> true).hasElement();
}
```

This code return true when there is data returned for a relevant username. But what I actually want is to retrieve only the "address" attribute from that returned Mono object and do some other processing.

FYI - Mono object returning works fine in my code

Comment: have you tried something like
List<UserEntity> user =  userRepository.findByUsername(userRequest.getUsername());

or 

UserEntity user =  userRepository.findByUsername(userRequest.getUsername());

Comment: Use `map` to retrieve the `address`.

Comment: @SandOfTime didnt work for me because findByUsername returns a Mono object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple map.

`user.map(usr -> usr.getWhatYouWant())`

Your code is wrong, anyway. Filter will not filter anything.

Comment: I wrote as System.out.print(user.map(usr -> usr.getAddress())); but it prints as MonoMap

Comment: Yes, you need to consume it somehow. Every Reactor "monad" needs to be consumed to give you a value. Normally you would want to send it somewhere, but in your case subscribe will be enough.
`user.map(usr -> usr.getAddress()).subscribe(System::out::println);`

Comment: You should avoid this as it breaks the Mono flow and makes your code synchronous. If you REALLY need to do this you can use `.block()`

Comment: it works  user.map(usr -> usr.getAddress()).subscribe(System.out::println);

Comment: do you know to assign that  printed value to a variable?

Comment: I just told you, use .block() and it will become synchronous.